# calculate if observed effect is larger than chance

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I have a data set in which my dependent variable is a score that can vary between 8 and 400.

```
set.seed(2023)
n <- 50
v <- rexp(n, .01)
obs <- mean(v)
```

I'd like to calculate if the effect I observe `obs` is larger than expected by chance. I understand that I need to build a null distribution. I tried

```
set.seed(2023)
prms <- replicate(10^4, mean(sample(v,n,rep=T)))
mean(abs(prms)>=abs(obs))
```

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: To me personally seems correct the last step is to compare your pvalue with the confidence level